# How to add a custom MIME type and override a default extension pattern?

Tags: java, mime, apache-tika

I am trying to add a custom mime type to Apache Tika.

I have the following `custom-mimetypes.xml` document in `org.apache.tika.mime` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info>
    <mime-type type="text/stringtemplategroup">
        <glob pattern="*.stg"/>
    </mime-type>
    <mime-type type="text/stringtemplate">
        <glob pattern="*.st"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

I am getting an error about a `Conflicting extension pattern .st`:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException: Conflicting extension pattern: .st
    at org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypesReader.startElement(MimeTypesReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
```

**How do I override the default entry for `*.st` extension and have it use my own?**

Comment: Did you fix it? I am facing the same problem. Let me know if you figured it out

Comment: I gave up TIka was a PITA because of some pretty bad design decisions about tightly coupling everything to a `File` object instead of an `InputStream` so using on Google App Engine was extremely hard and I had to fork and modify too much stuff to make it less painless. I ended up writing my own magic number classifier for the handful of types I support in my application. Tika is a good idea, terrible implementation.

Comment: Ok no luck for me then

Comment: real shame to read this as the guys in my development team forked tika and wrote lots of it to work from more of a stream model than remain coupled to File.  Sadly though they weren't permitted to push back to the project due to fear from the company they work for and that was 3 or more years ago now!

Answer (score 4):

Seems you [need to add](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/custom-mimetypes.xml) a `magic` tag with a priority

```
<mime-type type="text/stringtemplate">
    <magic priority="50">
        <!-- some match pattern -->
        <!-- <match value="[some characters]" type="string" offset="0" /> -->
    </magic>
    <glob pattern="*.st"/>
</mime-type>
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but in the end it does not fix the tight coupling to `File` even if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, much appreciated.

Comment: thanks for taking the time and trying to help [those that might find this](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: :) funny enough I got to this question by mistake when SO changed its UI. I didn't realize it was an old one until I have posted my answer. It caught my attention since I added custom magic numbers for Quark Xpress files to a Linux box acting as an Apple file server :p several years ago.